# Change layout of Microsoft Word Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

Here's how my TOC currently looks:

```
title1
title2
title3
```

Here's how I want it to look:

```
title1 - title2 - title3
```

How do I configure this? Is it possible to install a new template?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are after, but in Word 2010 you can do this:

[image: TOC Example]

Essentially you end up with 3 columns of items but the list goes vertically rather than horizontally.

Simply select the lines of the Table of Contents, go to the Page Layout tab, then select Columns and choose the number of columns you would like, as below.

[image]

I haven't found a way to make the list go horizontally yet, I'm going to continue to look for a short while.

Comment: I was thinking of manually editing it. Although I'm not sure the contents will still work when converted to Kindle. Isn't there a way of installing a new template?

Comment: You could well create a manual list of bookmarks pointing to each header, I don't see how this would act any differently to a table of contents when exported to pdf or other formats.